# Can't push an object to an array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
async function addContact(name, email, phone) {
  try {
    const data = await fsPromises.readFile(contactsPath, encoding);
    const updatedData = data.push({
      id: uid,
      name: name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
    });
    await fsPromises.writeFile(contactsPath, JSON.stringify(updatedData));
    console.log(updatedData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Getting an TypeError: data.push is not a function
at Object.addContact (/Users/jewkuza/Documents/goit-node-hw-01/contacts.js:43:30)

Comment: Can you check the type of data like ```console.log(typeof data)``` ? Since .push is an array function , i think data is object

Comment: if `fsPromises.readFile()` is just a wrapper to have promises around `fs.readFile()` then it returns `Promise<string | Buffer>` which is not an array of objects (!)

Comment: Reading from a file always reads a string, unless *your* `readFile` function somehow doesn't… Did you mean to `JSON.parse` the file contents…?

Comment: [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_readfile_options)'s promise doesn't fulfill with an array, it fulfills with a `Buffer` or a string. (String in your case, assuming `encoding` isn't `undefined`.) Also, [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, not the thing you pushed (inferring from what you do with `updatedData` after getting it from `push`). The best thing when you're getting unexpected results is to first check the documentation.

Comment: @deceze - Or a `Buffer`, but in this case string because an encoding was provided (assuming `encoding` isn't `undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a string, not an array, so there is no method `push` available.

You are probably missing a `JSON.parse()`:

```js
const data = await fsPromises.readFile(contactsPath, encoding);
const parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
const updatedData = parsedData.push({
      id: uid,
      name: name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact, that your code is just a snippet missing the definition of fsPromises, you have two bugs in here.

1. readFile returns a string and NOT an array (see here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)
2. you write the variable `updatedData` back to file. Array.push returns the new length of an array and NOT the updated array. You probably want to write data back.